# Is there a security loophole here?

Tags: security, web, encryption, uri, passcode

I have a web app which allows users to sign in to their accounts.
When they forget their password, or when they want to confirm their email, they receive an email with a one-time link (this link has a one-time code in its query string ie `example.com?code=encrypt(1234)`), which expires after a given time.

Now having this link will grant you the ability to change the user's password. Is this a security threat? Every package sent to and from this webapp is non-deterministically encrypted.

My questions in short:

1. Is it a problem, that I am using the same link to confirm an email, and reset the password depending on the situation?
2. Is it a problem that this one-time code is being sent as an encrypted string. What I mean is if the code is actually a string such as `h4drMfH/iVSPJGP0+zFlNQw......5bqnwU7Pdbo=` is there any way someone could predict the algorithm, or crack it if they know that the string codes for four digits? Ie could they work backwards to find the algorithm. Note that the result of `encrypt(123)` will be different if you do it twice.
3. Could someone get their hands on it by using the fact that the code is part of the querystring used by my web app?

Appreciated.

Comment: You're using non-deterministic encryption? And this depends on factors like how long the link is valid for, and how long the string is. A major threat would be someone just trying every possibility until they get a valid link. That attack should be made infeasible.

Comment: Yeah, I've made sure brute force will not be an option for attackers. Are there any other loopholes though? By this I mean some process which will give the attacker my passcode without them brute forcing. The link is valid for 2 hours but I can change that if it is too long.

Comment: The fact that you're using encryption does nothing for the security of your solution. Think of it this way - the attacker needs not to guess the code behind the encrypted string as the code itself is useless to them - your API will only accept it's encrypted form. Thus the encryption value is negated. What you need to do to mitigate the attack is a) make sure each code can only be accepted exactly once (which seems like you do already) b) make sure that only user requested codes are valid (i.e. no unsolicited codes are possible) c) implement rate limiting d) implement alerts for (..continued)

Comment: d) implement alerts for large number of requests of unsolicited codes from different IP addresses (this last one will let you know that someone clever is bruteforcing you). 

Beyond that, if the length of the reset link is not a concern, i would set up a dedicated RSA keypair with 4096/8192 key size JUST for the purposes of this link, and have the link actually be a CMS aka PKCS7 envelope encrypted with your cert. This can then contain things like `not before`, `not after` , `user id`, `requested time` etc in a way that would be opaque to the consumer, and you don't need to store any of this

Comment: Ok, I've done all of these points apart from envelope generation with PKCS (#7). As for the encryption I mentioned, all it does for me is provide me with a string which is longer than the original 4-digit code, and hence it makes for enhanced protection from brute force, am I right about this? Or am I just better off creating a pass-string with a different method rather than encrypting four digits?